# pythonで、画像のカメラ方位を変更して表示する方法

Tags: python, python3, windows, 画像

デジカメ画像をモニターに表示する際、固定されたカメラ方位を変更し、図のように画像の表示方位を変えた状態にするにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？[image: 画像のカメラ方位の変換]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pythonで画像処理はPillowらしいです。
https://note.nkmk.me/python-pillow-basic/

今回はこの辺でしょうか。
https://note.nkmk.me/python-pillow-concat-images/

> 余分な部分をカットして連結（結合）
>   PillowのImage.paste()では貼り付け先の画像の範囲外にはみ出した部分は無視される（カットされる）。

画像がつながるかは別にして、こんな感じでしょうか。

```
from PIL import Image

def pan_panorama(img, pan):
    """ pan: パンする角度、右回り（左へスライド）する
    """
    width = img.width
    pan = pan % 360 * width // 360
    dst = Image.new('RGB', img.size)
    dst.paste(img, (-pan, 0))
    dst.paste(img, (width-pan, 0))
    return dst

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = Image.open('panorama.jpg')
    new_img = pan_panorama(img, 120)
    new_img.save('panned.jpg')
```

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV を使って書いてみました。

`cv2.warpAffine()` に `M = [[1, 0, dx], [0, 1, dy]]` という行列を与えることで、画像を `(dx, dy)` だけ[平行移動することができます](http://labs.eecs.tottori-u.ac.jp/sd/Member/oyamada/OpenCV/html/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html#id5) (参考: ["Shift image content with OpenCV"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19068085/5989200))。この関数を使って左と右に平行移動させた後、2つを合成することで回転させています。

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def circular_shift_x(img, dx):
    rows, cols = img.shape[:2]
    if dx < 0:
        dx = cols + dx

    m = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, dx], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]], dtype='float32')
    right = cv2.warpAffine(img, m, (cols, rows))

    m = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, dx - cols], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]], dtype='float32')
    left = cv2.warpAffine(img, m, (cols, rows))

    # 現状 warpAffine の fillval はデフォルトで cvScalarAll(0) なので
    # 今回の場合は単に足し合わせるだけで合成できます。
    result = left + right
    return result

# 使用例
if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
    shifted_img = circular_shift_x(img, -100)

    cv2.imshow("window", shifted_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```